# How to write "select column name as "alias" from table name" in java odbc

Tags: java, oracle, select, odbc, ora-00911

```
String sql="select ID as \"Batch ID\", NAME as \"Batch Name\",START_DATE as \"Start date\",END_DATE as \"End date\"FROM BATCH order by NAME;";      
try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

This code returns an error

> java.sql.SQLException:ORA-00911:invalid character

I have also tried removing `\` from the query and replacing with `'`. But it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon character `;` is not a part of statement so you need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
\"End date\"FROM
```

There is your problem. You forgot a space then it is "End date"FROM.
Next time print your statement. Then run it in Oracle directly :)